# A single table indexes SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

How to view the indexes of a single table, not all tables, in SQL Server 2014?

Answer (score 1):

You can use SP_INDEXES or sp_helpindex

```
EXEC sp_indexes 'table name'
```

or

```
EXEC sp_helpindex 'table name'
```

Comment: empty set is returned

Comment: It means that the table has no indices